# Overwrite the same backup file every day

Tags: powershell, administration, backup, restore, disaster-recovery

I want to overwrite the same back up file of an sharepoint 2013 site collection by using the below powershell command line command:

```
Backup-SPSite -Identity http://xyz -Path D:\SP_BACKUPS\test.bak
```

How do I do this?

I am able to create one back up file for the first time, but from next time when i run the same command it is not overwritten.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `[Force][1]` Paramter.

```
Force = Specify to overwrite an existing backup file if it already exists.
```

Your command should be looks like this

```
Backup-SPSite -Identity http://xyz -Path D:\SP_BACKUPS\test.bak -force
```